# Please update http://law.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Tags: support

https://law.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account seems outdated.

As I can't ask questions about my jurisdiction. I wish to leave and delete my account only on Law beta *(not other stackexchange sites)*.

Comment: Is your statement about not being able to ask questions about your jurisdiction tied to the language question you asked?

Comment: @JasonAller : No, this is the same as mechanics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user2284570 Meaning what? (I'm not sure what the deal was with Mechanics.SE)

Comment: @cpast : same thing : legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that page:

> If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [contact form](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.