# Why was a question about private police deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Why was the question https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61740/overlap-between-public-and-private-entity deleted by @Cesar M please? It seems to me to be on topic for the Law stack. It seems to contain some misunderstandings, but correcting misunderstandings is an important part of what SE is for. I don't see anything obviously objectionable about the question, nor do I see that it violates any policy that I am aware of.

As not everyone can see deleted posts, the question read:

> Let's say a US county like Stafford, VA abolished its police. No legal change it simply doesn't allocate funds or isnt able to support it. Assume, for whatever reason the county administrator cant do anything about this but decides to pay, out of pocket for a new police force. Ie, the salary is paid directly out of his personal accounts. At what point does this new police force become the government?
>
> Is there any actual, legal distinction between government and private entities or is it just something that exists abstractly? Because say the administrator declares that his rentacops are the "real police" and enforce state law- at what point do the rentacops become "real police"? Is there any official process written down anywhere? Even if the local gov passes a one sentence ordinance saying "Bob's police are real" is that all?

Comment: My guess, based on Cesar's previous deletions, is that the asker is network-banned, and the deletion was to enforce the ban against evasion.  Though this wasn't merged into an account of someone who's network-banned, so the usual evidence isn't there.

Comment: @RyanM Correct!  Cesar actually merged it, but I didn't notice that before deleting it.

Answer (score 4):

User was deleted for network-wide abuses.  Whenever you see an unlinked username of the form `user#####` the account no longer exists, which means it was deleted, which can be either [done for cause by mods/managers](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1108/10) or [done by the owner of the account](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/123/10).

Answer (score 1):

### The user was deleted

I don’t know why, I didn’t do it.

When a user is deleted, all their posts are deleted too. There is an unknown (even to us) threshold of network activity beyond which a user can’t be deleted because deleting a user with hundreds or thousands of posts would clearly mess things up.

Comment: This is at least partly incorrect.  The post is zero-scored, so [it would not be deleted by a user deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/165261).  If the user were destroyed, then it would have been deleted, but I think (awaiting confirmation) that it would not be "via Vote" as the post history shows. It looks like it was manually deleted.

Comment: And there is no threshold beyond which a user cannot be deleted or destroyed. There is a threshold at which manual CM deletion is required, but that's irrelevant in the case of a low-rep user.